Should I use `weak self` on a custom stored queue?
I know that we can use strong self in DispatchQueues when we call it directly in the code, for example:
func foo() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        print(self.someProperty)
    }
}

But what about my custom queue, if I keep it in the class? Should I use weak self or it works the same and there is no need to worry about leaks?
class MyClass {
    
    let queue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "MyQueue",
        qos: .userInitiated
    )
    
    func foo() {
        queue.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            print(self.someProperty)
        }
    }
}

In this case my custom queue is stored in a class variable and probably I should use weak self. Or not?

queue.async closure does retain self without [weak self]. However, it's temporary, it will disappear immediately when dequeued. So there is no retain cycle here.
AFAIK, it's more like data flow than a retain cycle.

[weak self]: you might want to exit the scope early.
without [weak self]: you want to retain the object until the block is executed.


Thank you for the answer. So there is no difference whether queue is stored or not?

It can support: a meaningful label for debugging, or terminate the queue if needed.

I meant retain self difference, but thx anyway :)

@Oranutachi – “So there is no difference whether queue is stored or not?” – Nope. It doesn’t matter whether you store a reference to your custom queue or not. Either way, the only relevant factor is whether the closure dispatched to the queue captures self or not. And as sonle said, any strong references captured by the queue are resolved once it finishes executing, so it is generally a temporary state of affairs.
